# suppress all npm run output but show script output

Tags: npm

I'm running an npm script programatically (`npm run script`) and checking the output

The additional lines that npm puts at the start are breaking the script, is it possible to instruct npm to be quiet but still show the output from the script?

The lines I'm talking about are:

```
> my-package@1.0.0 do-thing /projects/my-package
> do-thing
```

I've tried `--silent` which suppresses the script too. I've tried `--quiet` which has no noticeable effect.

Answer (score 1):

For now I'm appending `| grep -v "^>" | sed '/^$/d'` to the end of the command which removes lines starting with > and blank lines. But this feels super clunky.

Comment: You can get away with just one sed command: `... | sed '/^>/d; /^$/d'`.